# How do I import a module only when needed?

Tags: import, python-2.7

I am writing different python modules for gupshup, nexmo, redrabitt, etc. service providers.

```
#gupshup.py
class Gupshup():
    def test():
        print 'gupshup test'
```

All the other modules have test() method with different content in them. I know whose test() to call. I want to write another module *provider*, which will look like -

```
#provider.py
def test():
    #call test() from any of the providers
```

I will pass some sting data as a command line argument which will have the name of the module.

But I don't want to import all the modules with `import providers.*` and then call the method like `providers.gupshup.test()`. Just by knowing whose test() I am going to call at run time, how do I load only nexmo module when I want to call it's test method?

Comment: Bloody hell, what are you doing? Your reasons for eschewing classes make no sense, what you appear to be after is still polymorphism (just without inheritance), you nevertheless still use inheritance and classes, the delegating class has no reason to exist, and the whole thing is generally a confusing mess. May I suggest you take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I want to put Car, Bike, Truck classes in separate files. So that when I need to add a vehicle I will add a file to a folder containing these classes. I know whose method - move() I am going to call. Car, Bike or Truck. but I don't want to import all the classes and then do Car.move().

Comment: Um... I'm still not sure what your problem is, but: (1) You can put as many classes as you want in whatever files (modules) you want. You can have multiple classes in a module, you can have them spread across different projects, etc. (2) You don't need to import *all* classes for that. But you do need at least the concrete class and its superclasses (obviously; otherwise, how are you going to inherit anything?). (3) If you don't need to inherit anything, then don't inherit. You don't necessarily need a superclass; use duck typing!

Comment: Should I delete this question as it seems confusing and write a new one?

Comment: You can edit it. Though it may help if you spent some time thinking and re-reading.

Comment: All right. Thank you. I will edit the question and try to explain it with actual problem. Decided to drop the delegation. Please read the question after edit

Comment: It's not clear how the "provider" module works. What determines which of the implementation modules is going to be needed?

Comment: It's still not entirely clear. You know whose method to call? How? Do you have a handle on the appropriate class or an instance of it? Then you don't even need to import.

Comment: @larsmans , See the new edited line starting with 'I will pass some sting data ...'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the module name in a string, you can use [`importlib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html) to import the module you want as needed:

```
from importlib import import_module

# e.g., test("gupshup")
def test(modulename):
    module = import_module(module_name)
    module.test()
```

`import_module` takes an optional second argument specifying the package from which to import the module.

If you additionally need to fetch a class from the module to get at the test method, you can get that from the module with `getattr`:

```
# e.g., test("gupshup", "Gupshup")
def test(modulename, classname):
    module = import_module(module_name)
    cls = getattr(module, classname)
    instance = cls()  # maybe pass arguments to the constructor
    instance.test()
```

Comment: great. this will do. +1 for the getattr method.

Comment: hey. tried using import_module with package-name as the second argument. it didn't work. did `module = import_module(module_name, 'providers')` where providers is a package containing the module gupshup. Note that providers package is in the same folder provider.py is in.

Comment: Hi, when I do `print __package__` it says `None`. Please refer my previous comment. I have put `import_module` in a file provider.py. And I have a folder providers in the same directory as provider.py. This providers folder is my package, I have put \__init\__.py in it. I have my modules gupshup.py, nexmo.py, redrabbit.py, and so on. in this package but can't import them.

Comment: In the module with the `test` function, can you `import gupshup` or `import providers.gupshup`?

Comment: yes. after setting the `$PYTHONPATH` I am able to do `import gupshup` and `from providers import gupshup` in the same dir as module.