# package imports libraries without even intializing class

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, python-import

The doubt is the if import a class from a package inside another package like this :

`from bar import foo`

Does it initialize the class? and if the module has an import at the first line like :

```py
import tensorflow

class foo:
   def __init__(self):
    # some things
```

Does it import the package even if we don't initialize the class from another file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it initialize the class?

No, it just gives your program access to that class - ready to be instantiated to an object when you want to (then it will call the `__init__` method).

> Does it import the package even if we don't initialize the class from another file?

Yes. You can see this as if you were to just `import bar`, then you would be able to access the imported tensorflow module with `bar.tensorflow`, i.e. it is actually imported even if there is *nothing* else in the module.

In your specific case of just importing `foo` from `bar`, we can still access tensorflow via the `inspect` built-in package that will give us a reference to `bar` and thus `.tensorflow` from `foo`.

```
import inspect
from bar import foo
print(inspect.getmodule(foo).itertools) #<module 'itertools' (built-in)>
```

*I'm not sure if there is an easier way to "get at" `bar` from `foo` without using `inspect`, but this is what I found for the purpose of explaining your case fully!*

Comment: I posted this question because I created a library in which there is a feature to change the detector and there are three detectors in which one of them requires tensorflow and tensorflow takes a long time to load. So How do u think I should structure it . Link to the file : https://github.com/ashwinvin/Visionlib/blob/master/visionlib/face/detection.py#L40

Comment: @ashwinvinod Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052129/how-do-i-import-a-module-only-when-needed